# Find solutions to $2\cos^2\frac x2=\cos^2x$ in range $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now. I have tried half-angle formulas but it seems like it doesn't work. A little help (or hint) would be really nice.

Comment: It is same as $1+\cos x=\cos^{2}x$. Find $\cos x$ first and then find $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
2\cos^{2} \frac{x}{2} &= \cos^{2} \frac{x}{2} + \cos^{2} \frac{x}{2} \\
&= \cos^{2} \frac{x}{2} - \sin^{2} \frac{x}{2} + 1 \\ &= \cos (2 \cdot \frac{x}{2}) +1 \\ &= \cos x +1.\end{align*}
Can you finish the problem from here?